# How to find out our candidate score

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Nomination phase for the election of moderator is underway and before nominating myself I would like to see my candidate score. Meanwhile only Manish has nominated himself for the election and his candidate score is like this

> candidate score 20/40
>       reputation 7k
>       moderation badges: 4/8
>       editing badges: 4/6
>       participation badges: 5/6

How can other candidates like myself find their candidate score with out nomination?

Comment: It bears mentioning again, but as M.A.Ramezani has pointed out below, these standards are very lofty for a site that is much more niche than a Stack Overflow or Super User.  If you (or anyone) feel you've been a positive contributor and want to do more, please nominate yourself.

Answer (score 10):

Well, let's look at the factors in play:

### Rep:

Being a trusted user wins 20 scores. In short, each 1k rep till 20k counts as 1 score, and the rep gets truncated. So, for me, someone with 2768 reps, it's 2 scores, outta 20.

### Moderation badges:

(Shamelessly copied from [the meta.SE post on this very nominal occurrence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/what-are-the-details-on-the-candidate-score-which-shows-during-an-election))

> Civic Duty, Cleanup, Deputy, Electorate, Marshal, Reviewer, Sportsmanship, Steward

Each count as one. So I'll get a 5/8 as I don't have `Marshal`, `Sportsmanship` and `Steward`.

### Editing badges:

> Copy Editor, Explainer, Organizer, Refiner, Strunk and White, Tag Editor

Just as my English vocab book says, instructions as above. For example, I miss `Copy editor` and `Refiner`, so I'll get a four outta six.

### Participation badges:

> Constituent, Convention, Enthusiast, Investor, Quorum, Yearling

Instructions as above.

**A final note**: These standard were set for *huge* sites like I dunno, ELU, Math.SE, SO and so on. So I won't be ashamed of the low score most of us get. You shouldn't too. :)

Comment: Nice score, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why you don't nominate though. You're really following this election! :)

Answer (score 10):

Out of curiosity, I dug around and there's a [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/297666/moderator-candidate-score) site.

You can get your user-id from your profile or user URL (e.g., mine is 5017). Enter it and you'll get the score.